# Trouble logging in via php/curl

Tags: php, curl

I have a problem with curl. I need to extract data from my profile with website (validity of the account). The problem is the lack of logging.

```
$login = "user";
$password = "passtest";
$ckfile = tempnam("./cookies", "cookies.txt");
$page_login = "http://host.tv/login.html";
$page_download = "http://host.tv/profil.html";
$post_data = "?login=$login&pass=$password";
$agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; pl; rv:1.8.0.3) Gecko/20060426 Firefox/1.5.0.3";


$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'GET /login.html HTTP/1.1';
$headers[] = 'Host: host.tv';
$headers[] = 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8';
$headers[] = 'Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4';
$headers[] = 'Referer: http://host.tv/login.html';
$headers[] = 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1';
$headers[] = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36';


$connect = curl_init ();


curl_setopt($connect, CURLOPT_URL, $page_login);
curl_setopt($connect, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1);
curl_setopt($connect, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt($connect, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);
curl_setopt($connect, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40);
curl_setopt($connect, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);        
curl_setopt($connect, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($connect, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($connect, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($connect, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($connect, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($connect, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
curl_exec($connect);


curl_setopt($connect, CURLOPT_URL, $page_download);
$page = curl_exec($connect);


curl_close($connect);  


echo $page;
```

The script does not logged do Accounts.

Comment: Not a good idea to post credentials ... (username/pass) - you should remove them...

Comment: Can you share the error message you are receiving?

Comment: @urban its probably an unpriviledged test account with no security significance, no problem sharing it

Answer (score 0):

you are doing some mistakes here,

1: don't manually create the GET / header, let curl create it for you with CURLOPT_URL / CURLOPT_HTTPGET

2: logging in is not a GET operation, its a POST operation.

and there's a lack of error checking on the curl return values.

here's an example of logging in, going to the profile page, and extract the account type (i guess it says "free account" or something, but i dont speak that language), using hhb_curl from https://github.com/divinity76/hhb_.inc.php/blob/master/hhb_.inc.php

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
require_once('hhb_.inc.php');
hhb_init();
$hc=new hhb_curl();
$hc->_setComfortableOptions();
//getting a session
$hc->exec('http://host.tv/login.html');

//logging in
$username='user';
$password='passtest';
$hc->setopt_array(array(
        CURLOPT_POST=>true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>http_build_query(array(
                'login'=>$username,
                'pass'=>$password,
                'logged'=>''//??            
        ))
));
$hc->exec('http://host.tv/login.html');
//TODO: confirm login was successful
$hc->exec('http://host.tv/profil.html');
//extract "account type" from your profile
$domd=@DOMDocument::loadHTML($hc->getResponseBody());
$accountType=trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', "\n", $domd->getElementById("content-top-right")->textContent));
echo $accountType.PHP_EOL;
```

output:

```
Konto:
Standard
Ważne
do:
Brak
```

Comment: I use PHP in version 5.4 in my raspberry pi (with the repository). I have notification:

    Warning: Unsupported declare 'strict_types' in hhb_.inc.php on line 2
    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '{' in hhb_.inc.php on line 4

Would you recommend me older function (without classes php)?

Comment: The result of my problem was adding an empty variable "logged". It works!

Comment: also you were not url encoding username/password, so if the username OR password contains spaces, or `&` or `=` , or a bunch of other characters, the server will get the wrong password, you should urlencode() them (in my example, i use http_build_query() to url-encode it for me)